# What topics can I ask about?

Tags: discussion, topic, documentation

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic currently has the following.  What modifications do you think should be made to it?

---

Ethereum Stack Exchange is for users and enthusiasts of Ethereum. It's built and run by you. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Ethereum. If you have a question about …

```
the open-source Ethereum client, Mist, Wallet or other Ethereum software
programming smart contracts and decentralized applications
the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) or Solidity or Serpent
the Ethereum network or protocol
Swarm and Whisper protocols and software
```

and it is not about …

```
investment advice
politics or philosophy
a site or software recommendation
speculation on the future
```

then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Related: [What should our documentation contain?](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/204/87)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a question about ...

- Specific issues with Ethereum, the smart contract enabled blockchain based consensus network, including Swarm and Whisper protocols
- Specific issues with Solidity, Serpent programming languages and the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM)
- Specific issues with smart contracts, decentralized applications and the web 3.0
- Open-source Ethereum clients, wallets, browsers, or other related tools and libraries

And not about ...

- Anything not directly related to the Ethereum, Swarm or Whisper protocols
- Sites, tools, libraries, or software recommendations
- Investment advices and speculation on the technological and financial future
- Discussing politics, governance, and philosophical questions
- Questions that are primarily opinion-based
- Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer